# Usar || en un string

Tags: c#

Hola estoy haciendo un código y estaba planeando usar `||` pero salta un error diciendo que

> || no puede ser aplicado en un string

por lo que estoy buscando una forma de sustituirlo, el código en cuestión:

```
void Start()
{
   string card = "O4";

   var cartasOro = new List<string>() { "O1", "O2", "O3", "O4", "O5", "O6", "O7", "OJ", "OQ", "OK" };

   if(card == "O2" || "O3")
   {
       Debug.Log("Si");
   }
}
```

Comment: ya probaste con ` if(card == "O2" || card =="O3")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saber si la variable `card` tiene el valor "02" o "04" el código correcto sería:

```
if (card == "02" || card == "04")
```

Esto es porque el operador lógico `||` (or) opera sobre valores de tipo booleano, que es lo que devuelve el resultado de cada comparación.

De la manera en que lo has escrito, pareciera que quieres aplicar el operador `||` sobre las cadenas "02" y "03", y eso no solo no es posible sino que no tiene sentido.

Sé que al principio esto es algo confuso, pero a medida que vas comprendiendo como funciona el procesador y el compilador, se entiende mejor.

Tratando de abonar en esa dirección, por ahora te pido que pienses que cada comparación devuelve un valor lógico (Verdadero o Falso), que son sobre los que opera `||`.

Así, cuando tu programa se está ejecutando se evalúa la primera comparación:

```
card == "02"
```

Que va a devolver `False`.

Luego se evalúa la segunda comparación

```
card == "03"
```

Que también va a devolver `False`.

Es hasta entonces que se evalúa el operador `||`

```
False || False
```

De la tabla de verdad de or, sabemos que esto devuelve `False`

Es hasta entonces que se evalúa el if

```
if (False)
```

Por lo que la ejecución no entrará al bloque que está dentro del if.

Los procesadores solo pueden ir así, paso a paso, con pasos muy pequeños. Con ayuda de los compiladores e interpretes podemos escribir código más cercano al lenguaje *natural* y a la manera de pensar de los humanos. Estos procesos *transforman* el código de alto nivel en los cientos, miles y millones de pequeñas instrucciones necesarias para ejecutar lo que el código representa.

Hay ocasiones, sin embargo, en las que nos vemos obligados a escribir las cosas de manera que puedan interpretarse correctamente, como en este caso.

Answer (score 2):

La forma "clásica" de realizar esa comprobación es:

```
if (card == "O2" || card == "O3") {  }
```

Desde .net 7.0 tambien podrías hacer:

```
if (card is "O2" or "O3") {   }
```

La cual mientras más comparaciones hagas es progresivamente más corto que la versión clásica.

Comment: Estaría bueno mencionar que se llama [*pattern matching*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching)